# Conditional expectation of $E[X|Y-X,Z+X]$ given three independent Gaussian RVs $(X,Y,Z)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, conditional-expectation

Let $X \sim (0,\sigma_x^2), Y \sim (0,\sigma_y^2), Z \sim (0,\sigma_z^2)$ be independent Gaussian RVs. I'm trying to compute $E[X|Y-X,Z+X]$. Here is what I've tried.

Set $A=Y-X, B=Z+X$, then, $X = \frac{B-A-Z+Y}{2}$,

\begin{align}
E[X|Y-X,Z+X]&=E[\frac{B-A-Z+Y}{2}|A,B]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}[E[B|A,B]-E[A|A,B]-E[Z|A,B]+E[Y|A,B]]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}[B-A-E[Z|Z+X]+E[Y|Y-X]]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}[Z+X-Y+X-\frac{\sigma_z^2}{\sigma_z^2+\sigma_x^2}(Z+X)+\frac{\sigma_y^2}{\sigma_y^2+\sigma_x^2}(Y-X)]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}[\frac{\sigma_x^2}{\sigma_z^2+\sigma_x^2}(Z+X) - \frac{\sigma_x^2}{\sigma_y^2+\sigma_x^2}(Y-X)].
\end{align}
Is this proof correct?

Comment: $E(Z \mid A, B) = E(Z \mid B)$ need not be true. It would be true if $\sigma(B,Z) = \sigma(X,Z)$ were independent of $\sigma(A) = \sigma(Y-X)$ and this is clearly not true. I am afraid you might need to do all calculation by hand; namely, finding the joint density of $(x, y-x, x+z)$, then integrating the first coordinate to find the joint density of $(y-x,x+z),$ find the conditional density and finally integrating the conditional density.

Comment: @WilliamM. Thank you for correction. Can I understand this conditional expectation as the MMSE estimator of $X$ given $Y-X,Z+X$ and since they are jointly gaussian, the linear MMSE estimator coincides with the MMSE estimator. Then, I compute it by finding $a,b$ such that $a,b$ minimizes $E[(X-a(Y-X)-b(Z+X))^2]$?

Comment: Intuitively I might expect it to be larger in magnitude than your final expression when $Z+X$ and $Y-X$ have opposite signs (i.e. when $X+Z$ and $X-Y$ have the same sign): seeing that would suggest to me that $X$ was probably bigger.

Comment: If you know that the conditional expectation is given as an optimization problem, then that might be a faster approach to the problem.

Comment: @WilliamM. Yes, I'm trying to estimate $\hat{X}$ given $Y-X,Z+X$ such that $E[(X-\hat{X})^2]$ is minimized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by William M, the problem in your attempt is that $E(Z \mid A, B) = E(Z \mid B)$ is not true in general.

Here is a way to find $\mathbb E[X|Y-X,Z+X]$: for each $a,b\in\mathbb R$,
$$
\mathbb E[X|Y-X,Z+X]=\mathbb E[X-a(Y-X)-b(Z+X)|Y-X,Z+X]+a(Y-X)+b(Z+X).
$$
If we choose $a_0$ and $b_0$ such that $X-a(Y-X)-b(Z+X)$ is independent of the vector $(Y-X,Z+X)$, then we will get
$$
\mathbb E[X|Y-X,Z+X]=a_0(Y-X)+b_0(Z+X).
$$
In order to find $(a_0,b_0)$, note that since the vector $(X,Y,Z)$ is Gaussian, it suffices to solve in $(a,b)$
$$
\operatorname{Cov}\left(X-a(Y-X)-b(Z+X),Y-X\right)=\operatorname{Cov}\left(X-a(Y-X)-b(Z+X),Z+X\right)=0,
$$
which will give a linear system in $(a,b)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:  find the joint distribution of $(X, Y - X, Z + X)$ using the [affine transformation property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Affine_transformation) of multivariate distribution, then apply the [conditional distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions) theorem for multivariate normal random vectors.

Answer (score 0):

This is mechanized in Mathematica 13.2:

```
Expectation[x \[Conditioned] y - x == t && z + x == s, {x \[Distributed] 
NormalDistribution[0, \[Sigma][x]],  z \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, \[Sigma][z]], 
y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, \[Sigma][y]]}]
```

$$\frac{t \sigma (x)^2 \sigma (y)^2-s \sigma (x)^2 \sigma (z)^2}{\sigma (x)^2 \sigma (y)^2+\sigma (x)^2 \sigma (z)^2+\sigma (y)^2 \sigma (z)^2}
$$